# Bash: Gathering all inputs at once, without waiting for the process to end

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop, append, user-input

I have been writing a bash script in which the process depends on the user's input, but it is a 1min process, and if the user wants to do it more than once, he will have to wait for the loop to finish.
Here is the code:

```
while [[ ! "$addstr" =~ ^[Nn](.*)?$ ]]; do
    read -p "[*] String to permute around: " string
    echo; sleep 0.1s

    while [[ ! "$string" =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ ]]; do
        echo "[!] Only alphanumeric strings are allowed!"; sleep 0.1s
        read -p "=> " string
        echo; sleep 0.1s
    done

    ## PROCESS ##

    echo "[?] Do you want to permute around another string?"; sleep 0.1s
    read -p "=> " addstr
    echo; sleep 0.1s

    while [[ ! "$addstr" =~ ^[YyNn](.*)?$ ]]; do
        echo "[!] Type again:"
        read -p "=> " addstr
        echo; sleep 0.1s
    done
done
```

What i want to do is to allow the user to enter all strings AT ONCE, storing the variables for each of them and running the process as many times as it needs... I tryed a lot of things, even appending a "$counter" after "$string" but couldn't make this work, i believe it's something very simple and i just don't have the knowledge..

Comment: remove the sleeps, you'll speed up the process.

Comment: I like the way the program flows with them. Just a personal thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the script to read input from stdin. Then the user can redirect from a file.

Your script then becomes:

```
while IFS= read -r string; do
    if [[ ! "$string" =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ ]]; do
        echo "[!] Only alphanumeric strings are allowed! $string"
        continue
    fi

    ## PROCESS ##
done
```

And the user types something like

```
./yourscript < file.with.strings
```

or various other ways to feed data to your script's stdin.

---

Another thought: gather all the inputs up front:

```
inputs=()
while true; do
    read -p "[*] String to permute around: " string
    echo; sleep 0.1s

    while [[ ! "$string" =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]]; do
        echo "[!] Only alphanumeric strings are allowed!"; sleep 0.1s
        read -p "=> " string
        echo; sleep 0.1s
    done

    # store the user input
    inputs+=( "$string" )

    echo "[?] Do you want to permute around another string?"; sleep 0.1s
    read -p "=> " addstr
    echo; sleep 0.1s

    while [[ ! "$addstr" =~ ^[[:blank:]]*[YyNn] ]]; do
        echo "[!] Type again:"
        read -p "=> " addstr
        echo; sleep 0.1s
    done

    [[ "$addstr" =~ ^[[:blank:]]*[Nn] ]] && break
done

## PROCESS ##
for string in "${inputs[@]}"; do
    process "$string"
done
```

Comment: Also, your regex can be written with a character class like `^[[:alnum:]]+$`

Comment: Can't do it because it's only a portion of a bigger program.. But that made sense, thank you. About the regex: Yeah, totally forgot about that. Thank you again!

Comment: That seems to make sense, but can you explain the syntax added, please? I am still learning and couldn't quite get some stuff, like the 'inputs()', the 'inputs+=( "$string" )' and the '${inputs[@]}'.. Could you please explain?

Comment: That's bash array syntax. Declare an empty array, add an element to it, iterate over it